# printable table with partial bolding/italics within a cell

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table, kable

I'm looking for a way to print out a table from R, but with formatting *within* a cell, like having some of the text within a cell be bold or italic. Normally I would first make the appropriate `data.frame`/`tibble` and then I'd format and print it using a package like `huxtable` or `kable`. Looking over documentation for [`huxtable`](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html) or [`kableExtra`](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html), it seems as though both packages treat formatting as properties of cells, implying that within-cell formatting is either unsupported or must be implemented some other way.

If I was making a `ggplot`, I'd use `expression` for text formatting, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=mtcars) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(bold("bold part"), " not bold part")))
```

[image]

I thought I could be clever by putting expressions into a `data.frame`, but this doesn't seem to be supported:

```r
data.frame(var = c(expression(paste(bold("bold part"), "not bold part")),
                   expression(paste(bold("bold part"), "not bold part"))
))
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ""expression"" to a data.frame
```

Comment: I think you'll find the gridtable package useful: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes to data tables, I recommend you use the `grid` and `gridExtra` packages to construct your table and then make changes to the theme parameters.

Without any data to play with I can't see exactly what you want but here's a general idea of what you could do (see below). I've included other aesthetic parameters, for future reference.

You could then generate a pdf output to your C drive, which could then be printed.

```
d <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                B = c(6,7,8,9,10),
                C = c(11,12,13,14,15))

pdf("Test.pdf", height = 11, width = 10)
grid.table(d, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme_minimal(
core=list(fg_params=list(
hjust=0, 
x=0.1, 
fontface=matrix(c(1,2,3)))))) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Re huxtable, you're correct, but you can get round it. Here's a 1 row, 1 column example, assuming you are printing to HTML:

```
my_hux <- huxtable("<b>Bold part</b> Not bold part")
escape_contents(my_hux)[1, 1] <- FALSE
```

You can include arbitrary HTML. Something similar would work for TeX, obviously with TeX formatting instead.